# Как активировать строку ввода через кнопку?

Tags: javascript, input

Допустим, есть строка поиска.

```html
<div class="test-Searchbar"><input></div>
```

В другой части экрана есть кнопка на JS. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на эту кнопку происходила активация строки ввода?

Клик на "test-Searchbar" ничего не дал

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div class="test-Searchbar"><input></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.test-Searchbar input').focus()">Go To Input</button>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null` :c

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 Что это? Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе, а потом кнопку "Go To Input".